# Visualizing gcc error messages

Tags: gcc

Are there any programs which can be used to visualize error messages from gcc.
I am imagining something which will allow interactively to collapse all those long template typenames, color code different parts of the error message and what not.

Comment: In all fairness you get used to them after a while.

Comment: Compiling under emacs, there is those different colors for erros, warnings. Also there you can jump to error/warning line and fix the problem.

Comment: If your code can compile with [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), then it will give you [more helpful error messages](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long template errors, related to stl you can use [stlfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html)
It's an error decryptor

Answer (score 5):

I've used [pretty make](http://phil.freehackers.org/pretty-make/index.html) in the past. Not sure how it works with c++ template error messages, but it does help visualize compiler output in general.

Then there's also [Color GCC](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html), which does color error and warning messages from gcc. Probably not as advanced as you'd like it to be, but it may be something at least :)